# Failing to set iOS App Icon in qmake

Tags: ios, qt, icons

I used the following code in my qmake file (.pro) of the QT iOS Application.

```
ios{
    QMAKE_INFO_PLIST = ../../packages/ios/Info.plist
    ios_icon.files = $$files(../../packages/ios/icons/AppIcon*.png)
    QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA += ios_icon
}
```

and the specified path contains all png files.

But the Application file not getting the icon. Is there any thing I am missing?

Working on mac version 10.9.5.
Qt 5.5

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

https://beter93.wordpress.com/2014/10/30/how-to-set-an-application-icon-for-ios-with-qt5-1/

**If you need change your application name :**

https://beter93.wordpress.com/2014/10/31/how-to-change-an-ios-application-name-developed-with-qt/